# How do I set up a legend in the pie Chart?

Tags: highcharts

I use a highcharts type pie, and when hovering over my home elements outside the chart I want to highlight the pie as when hovering over the legend
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `point.setState()` method to achieve this:

```
document.getElementById("div").onmouseover = function() {
  chart.series[0].points.forEach(point => {
    if (point.name == 'Chrome') {
      point.setState('select')
    } else {
      point.setState('inactive')
    }
  })
}
document.getElementById("div").onmouseout = function() {
  chart.series[0].points.forEach(point => {
    point.setState('normal')
  })
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nwozaqxj/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#setState

Comment: That's a great way! But I don't always have access to the chart instance. How can I do this by changing the settings object?

Comment: What about moving the code to the `load()` chart event? Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/drwnc5xp/

Comment: Great solution! I implemented getting the instance from load() via callback . But your solution is good too, thank you for your help!